# Connect a producer to kafka topics

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have a server A. In server A I have installed kafka and started the kafka and zookeeper.
I also created a topic as my_topic.
Now I have an application B running in server B. Application B is having some data and I want to push those data to the my_topic in Server A. How to do that using kafka producer.
Do I need to install kafka in server B as well and create a producer in server B ?
If yes , how the messages from server B will be pushed to topics in server A ? What would be the medium ?

Answer (score 0):

Java applications write data to Kafka topics
with `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer`.
In order to specify which Kafka you want to send your data, you should set its property `"bootstrap.servers"` to `your kafka server address`.
You can find a code example in [KafkaProducer documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html)